# "other than" vs "except"

Tags: word-choice

Which one sounds best: "other than" or "except"?

1) I can’t think anyone **other than** you to send my first script.

2) I can’t think anyone **except** you to send my first script.

Comment: Both would be ok if you included "of": "I can't think *of* anyone... Also check what you want to say: "to send the script" or "to send the script *to*"?

Comment: Thank you @Stephie for the answer. "I can’t think of anyone other than you to send my first script." Isn't fine?

Comment: If you want the other person to put your script into the mailbox...

Comment: Ouch! If I want to submit to somebody, then?

Comment: Then you send it *to* someone. Means in this case two "to"s, one for the infinitive, one for the direction. For phrasing, see my first comment.

Comment: I agree with @Stephie – both _other than_ and _except_ work just fine, but the rest of the sentence reads a bit awkward. We could say: _"When it was time for me to decide where to send my first script, I couldn't think of anyone other than you"_ – and we could also replace that _other than_ with _except_.)

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to involve an indirect object: *"I can’t think of anyone other than you(i) to send __(i) my first script"*. This too seems to resist having a gap in indirect object location. This seems somewhat similar to this thread, [“Whom would you offer the ride?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258687/whom-would-you-offer-the-ride), which also involves an indirect object gap. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences sound OK if you want your interlocutor to send your script (say to the printers), but you need to add the preposition "of" after think.  However, if you are the sender and your interlocutor is the recipient, then your sentences aren't correct. I think you can rephrase your sentence as follows:

I can't think of anyone other than/except you to send my script to.

I can't think of sending my first script to anyone other than/except you.

Comment: Stephie. Thanks for your comments. I have edited my answer accordingly.